# A century-old term for a dog waste collector

Tags: word-request

I believe 100 years ago, or thereabouts, there was a term in use for men whose sole job was to collect dog or other animal droppings.

I came across this term over ten years ago and the term has evaded me ever since! What is the old term for a dog waste collector?

Comment: This question is not about learning  English and should have been moved to ELU.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pure_finder) defines ***pure finder*** (with alternatives such as *pure collector* and *pure gatherer*) as follows, with attestations from Robert Hughes' 1987 book *The Fatal Shore* and Henry Mayhew's *London Labour and the London Poor* (1851):

> *(obsolete)* Someone who collected dog faeces for sale to tanneries (which used it as a siccative for bookbinding leather). Undertaken by poor people in Britain in the 18th and 19th centuries.

[Vet Times](https://www.vettimes.co.uk/app/uploads/wp-post-to-pdf-enhanced-cache/1/a-dirty-job-but-not-to-be-sniffed-at.pdf) gives a more detailed historical account, of which an excerpt is given here:

> The heyday of the **pure-finder** was between the 1830s and 1930s. The early adopters of this trade started out as “bunters” or rag-gatherers, who collected fabric scraps to sell on (the Victorians were arguably the consummate recyclers). These enterprising individuals spotted a need and diversified into picking up dog faeces.
>
> Pure-finders haunted the streets where populations of stray dogs lived. They collected their “booty” in a handled bucket, which they kept covered to conceal the contents. Some collectors wore a black leather glove to harvest their finds and protect their hands, but others dispensed with the glove, saying it was easier to wash their hands after work than to keep the glove fit for use.
>
> However, this job was not to be sniffed at and in the early days it proved satisfyingly lucrative as many people made a good living at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you are looking for may be "pure-picker"? Henry Mayhew's "London Labour and the London Poor" Vol 1 [available here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55998) has the passage:

> After these we have the STREET-FINDERS, or those who, as I said before,
>   literally “pick up” their living in the public thoroughfares. They are
>   the “pure” pickers, or those who live by gathering dogs’-dung; the
>   cigar-end finders, or “hard-ups,” as they are called, who collect the
>   refuse pieces of smoked cigars from the gutters, and having dried them,
>   sell them as tobacco to the very poor; the dredgermen or coal-finders;
>   the mud-larks, the bone-grubbers; and the sewer-hunters.

"Pure" is a strange name for the commodity to a modern mind, but I believe it was sought after for use in the tanning trade (another occupation which I would not have wanted).

Comment: No I don’t think that this the exact word but it is similar in the case that it was 2 words that could be otherwise used singularly in a different context, but in this case was in fact one word,

Comment: Vol 2 of Mayhew's classic work is also available from Gutenberg and includes a long account of the pure trade. It might be worth looking through to see if any other terms fit your memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could be thinking of *mucker*, which is defined by the Oxford English Dictionary as:

> A person who removes dung, *esp*. a cleaner of stables

This word dates back to [Middle English as a surname](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED28875/track?counter=1&search_id=2980122) and it’s still in use today, albeit rarely.

Comment: Hi Laurel, no it was not muck-raker, however, again it was 2 words that was joined together for this profession

Answer (score 0):

There are a few old terms, but the one I think most likely fits your request is *muckraker*. The term originally referred to someone who cleared the streets from dung, but later on came to have a figurative use to describe someone who searches for scandals to expose, such as newspaper hacks.

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/muckraker):

> 1675–85; obsolete muck rake a rake for use on muck or dung.

Other terms include *Gong farmer*, which was the Tudor name to describe someone who dug out and removed human excrement from privies and cesspits. And lastly, I'm not sure if this was a genuine medieval title, but the medieval-themed fantasy game *Warhammer* contains a character called a *Dung Collector* that removes animal dung from the streets.

I know you said you think the term is from only 100 years ago and the terms I suggested are from a much older age, but I don't know of such a profession in Edwardian England. A little over 100 years in Victorian England *tanners* would collect dog poo from the streets to use in the tanning process - the colouring of leather.

Comment: I was thinking muckraker at first but I could not find any evidence that it was ever used to refer to people who worked with literal dung. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Laurel Yes the origin was in the dictionary, i've added that in as a link

Comment: isn’t that referring to the tool and not a person?